# Struggling associating pre-defined array elements C#

Tags: c#, arrays

As a part of a C# program, I receive a byte array from an IO port and save it to a byte array as:

```
byte[] myBytes = { AA, BB, CC }
```

But the received array is random, so it can also be:

```
byte[] myBytes = { BB, AA, CC }
```

Now each byte reparents a string AA is "Animal", BB is "Bus", CC is "Computer". This information is written on paper so I know which byte is associated with a particular string.

So when I receive a random array, I want to create the associated string array "in the same order with the byte array". For example, if I receive { CC, BB, AA } then I want by code to create { "Computer", "Bus", "Animal" } array.

But I couldn't figure out what to use and how to implement the code here. I need to kind of pre associate the bytes to strings and then proceed but exceeding my experience at the moment.

Comment: 1) Loop through your array, byte-by-byte. 2) Turn each byte into its corresponding string, and add to the result. You could do step 2 using an `if/else if` statement, or a switch statement/expression, or a dictionary lookup. Which of those two steps are you having trouble with?

Comment: @canton7 In real the array will be much longer. So I don't want to write from scratch a for loop algorithm which will be difficult. Basically I dont know which direction to go from here. How can I pre associate the bytes to strings in the same order, so that when I receive a byte array I can create the corresponding string array. So back to your question, I don't even know where to start so its not about getting stuck at a particular point. I tried to write a code but was too messy with all those for loops.

Comment: There will only be 1 loop -- not sure how you're getting multiple loops. Please share the code you've written so far

Comment: @canton7 There will not be one loop because I simplified it for the question, in real there is also AB. It is part of a complex protocol.

Comment: @user1999 If you oversimplify the question, you will get an oversimplified answer..

Comment: @user1999 It doesn't matter -- you should only need 1 `for` loop to loop through the byte array

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay The answer below seems adequate for me. I was looking for some sort of association. Im new to C#

Comment: @user1999 Ok, the `Select` below uses a single loop internally. And the dictionary lookup is a `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @user1999 See my answer. Notice how there's only 1 loop!

Comment: @canton7 Yes I see. Especially your second method to me looks very definitive and practical. I complied it. You may need semicolon after the dictionary though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simple approaches which should be easy to understand.

This one simply loops through each byte in the array, and uses an `if/else if`:

```
byte[] myBytes = { 0xBB, 0xAA, 0xCC };
string[] result = new string[myBytes.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < myBytes.Length; i++)
{
    byte value = myBytes[i];

    if (value == 0xAA)
    {
        result[i] = "Animal";
    }
    else if (value == 0xBB)
    {
        result[i] = "Bus";
    }
    else if (value == 0xCC)
    {
        result[i] = "Computer";
    }
    else
    {
        // What do you want to do here?
    }
}
```

You can simplify that `if/else` a bit by using a dictionary:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<byte, string>()
{
    { 0xAA, "Animal" },
    { 0xBB, "Bus" },
    { 0xCC, "Computer" },
};

byte[] myBytes = { 0xBB, 0xAA, 0xCC };
string[] result = new string[myBytes.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < myBytes.Length; i++)
{
    byte value = myBytes[i];

    if (lookup.TryGetValue(value, out string stringValue))
    {
        result[i] = stringValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // What do you want to do here?
    }
}
```

Or a switch expression:

```
byte[] myBytes = { 0xBB, 0xAA, 0xCC };
string[] result = new string[myBytes.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < myBytes.Length; i++)
{
    byte value = myBytes[i];
    result[i] = value switch
    {
        0xAA => "Animal",
        0xBB => "Bus",
        0xCC => "Computer",
        _ => // What do you want to do here?
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary containing the mapping from byte to string:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<byte,string>
{
        {AA, "Animal"},
        {BB, "Bus"},
        {CC, "Computer"}
 };
```

Then you can use LINQ to create a string array:

```
var myStrings = myBytes.Select(x => dict.TryGetValue(x, out string value) ? value : "Unknown").ToArray();
```

`Select` will loop over your array and for each entry it will try to get the value from the dictionary. If it suceeds, `Select` will take this value, otherwise the default string `Unknown`. With `ToArray`, this values will be stored in a new array.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ssIZG

Comment: 1) Code that compiles is good, answers which don't compile are bad. Please make sure your code compiles! 2) Some explanation of the code would be good. Particularly as the OP seems very new to C#, throwing linq in there without any explanation is not helpful